# Force signal from testbench

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

**The Problem**

In my design there is a counter used for delays. For simulation purposes I would like to cap it's maximum value witout editing any of the production code. This is done in order to speed up the simulation.

**What I've tried**

I wanted to check if it exceeds a maximum value from my testbench, and if it does I wanted to set it to that value. My first try looked like this:

```
alias ext_delay is << signal .architecture.in.my.production.code.delay : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) >>;
cap_delay : process (ext_delay) is
    constant max_value : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00001000"
begin
    if ext_delay > max_value then
        ext_delay <= max_value;
    end if:
end process cap_delay;
```

However, this causes the delay signal in the architecture to always be `'U'`, probably since it was driven by multiple processes. I then tried it by using the `force` keyword, which succeeded in changing the value and did not cause it to become `'U'`, but then I need a way to release it again the next time it gets decremented.

Comment: Have you tried using `release` to 'undo' your `force`? Example [here](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_small/#force)

Comment: I know, but I don't know how I should time that. I can't do `ext_delay <= force max_value, release after 10 ns;`, that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you could update the question with your code that uses `force`

Comment: it's just the assignment line that gets changed to `ext_delay <= force max_value;`.

Comment: Design for test should be part of your development process. Treating inadequate code as golden doesn't help you improve anything. A better solution would be to use top-level generics to control delays or have a configurable register file to modify behavior. Hacking around with forced signals is a poor solution. It should only be used for debugging, not verification.

Comment: The delays are not hardcoded in the VHDL, they are read from a flash memory on the device. However,  in the test we want to use the same flash files that are used on the hardware without needing to generate new ones with shorter delay just for the testbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. By changing to a wait-based process I can easily use a time delay. The full solution I went with looks like this:

```
alias ext_delay is << signal .architecture.in.my.production.code.delay : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) >>;
cap_delay : process is
    constant max_value : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00001000"
begin
    wait until ext_delay > max_value then
        ext_delay <= force max_value;
    wait for 10 ns;
        ext_delay <= release;
end process cap_delay;
```

Comment: This should probably read `wait until ...;` without the `then` on line 5, same as the `wait for 10 ns;` line.

Comment: @mbschenkel, that is possible, can't verfiy that right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to determine if your VHDL code is executed in simulation or used for synthesis. This code can be encapsulated in a function, so you can check it in your VHDL code. For example you can define different max values for your counter.

```
function SIMULATION return boolean is
  variable ret : boolean;
begin
  ret := false;
  --synthesis translate_off
  if Is_X('X') then ret := true; end if;
  --synthesis translate_on
  return  ret;
end function;
```

In addition to this an if-then-else function is helpful to choose different values in a constant declaration:

```
function ite(cond : BOOLEAN; value1 : INTEGER; value2 : INTEGER) return INTEGER is
begin
  if cond then
    return value1;
  else
    return value2;
  end if;
end function;
```

Example counter:

```
signal Counter_us : UNSIGNED(23 downto 0) := (others => '0');

[...]

process(Clock)
  constant COUNTER_MAX : POSITIVE := ite(SIMULATION, 100, 10000);
begin
  if rising_edge(Clock) then
    if (Counter_us >= COUNTER_MAX) then
      Counter_us <= (others => '0');
    else
      Counter_us <= Counter_us + 1;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

For more function like SIMULATION and ite(..) have a look into the [PoC.utils](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl) package.

Comment: Yes, but as I've stated, I don't want to edit any of the production code, as that would require recertifiying parts of it that are already on a release branch. I posted the solution I went with.

Answer (score -1):

Did you used **Noforce** keyword,
it release the value of the signal

Comment: yeah try to use it first from waveform right click > noforce

Comment: noforce is a modelsim command, the VHDL keyword is `release`. I know about that, but I don't know how I should time that.

Comment: you can use variables inside your testbench, i didn't try it for signals but i use variables to handle files